# Processing concurrent AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, concurrency, promise

I am trying to process concurrent AJAX requests with vanilla JavaScript. Below is the sample code I've been working with

```
function getInfoViaConcurrency(ids) {
  let infoPromiseArr = ids.map(id=> { infoPromiseArr.push(getInfoViaAjax(id)); });

  return Promise.all(infoPromiseArr).then(values => { return values; });
}

function getInfoViaAjax(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', `API URL`);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
      }
      else {
          reject(xhr.status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  })
}
```

Does using promise.all suffice to promote concurrency? can someone suggest any improvements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does using promise.all suffice to promote concurrency?

It's not really `Promise.all` that does it. You're starting your requests without waiting for the previous ones to complete, so yes, they run concurrently. All `Promise.all` does is let you know when all of the promises you give it have resolved (or when the first one rejects).

> can someone suggest any improvements?

Some thoughts:

- In `getInfoViaConcurrency`:

  1. Your use of `map` is incorrect, kind of a mash-up of your original `forEach` (from your now-deleted post on SO) and `map`
  2. You can pass `getInfoViaAjax` directly to `map`
  3. The `then` handler on the `Promise.all` serves no purpose and can be removed
- In `getInfoViaAjax`, you could use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) on modern browsers rather than `XMLHttpRequest`

So `getInfoViaConcurrency` could be:

```
function getInfoViaConcurrency(ids) {
  return Promise.all(ids.map(getInfoViaAjax));
}
```

and if you want to use `fetch`, `getInfoViaAjax` could be:

```
function getInfoViaAjax(id) {
  return fetch({/*...appropriate options and URL...*/}).then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(/*...whatever you want to say here...*/);
      }
      return response.text();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering this in SO and in here with more details.